# Cross_val_score is not working with roc_auc and multiclass

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, roc

**What I want to do:**

I wish to compute a `cross_val_score` using `roc_auc` on a multiclass problem

**What I tried to do:**

Here is a reproducible example made with iris data set.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score  
iris = load_iris()
X = pd.DataFrame(data=iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
```

I one hot encode my target

```
encoder = OneHotEncoder()
y = encoder.fit_transform(pd.DataFrame(iris.target)).toarray()
```

I use a decision tree classifier

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1)
```

Finaly I perform cross val

```
cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=3, scoring="roc_auc")
```

**What is failing:**

This last line throw the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-91dc6fa67512> in <module>()
----> 1 cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=3, scoring="roc_auc")

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch)
    340                                 n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose,
    341                                 fit_params=fit_params,
--> 342                                 pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
    343     return cv_results['test_score']
    344 

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score)
    204             fit_params, return_train_score=return_train_score,
    205             return_times=True)
--> 206         for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
    207 
    208     if return_train_score:

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    777             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    778             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 779             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    780                 self._iterating = True
    781             else:

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    623                 return False
    624             else:
--> 625                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    626                 return True
    627 

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    586         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
    587         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 588         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    589         self._jobs.append(job)
    590 

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    109     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    110         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 111         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    112         if callback:
    113             callback(result)

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    330         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    331         # arguments in memory
--> 332         self.results = batch()
    333 
    334     def get(self):

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, error_score)
    486         fit_time = time.time() - start_time
    487         # _score will return dict if is_multimetric is True
--> 488         test_scores = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer, is_multimetric)
    489         score_time = time.time() - start_time - fit_time
    490         if return_train_score:

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer, is_multimetric)
    521     """
    522     if is_multimetric:
--> 523         return _multimetric_score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    524     else:
    525         if y_test is None:

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _multimetric_score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorers)
    551             score = scorer(estimator, X_test)
    552         else:
--> 553             score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
    554 
    555         if hasattr(score, 'item'):

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py in __call__(self, clf, X, y, sample_weight)
    204                                                  **self._kwargs)
    205         else:
--> 206             return self._sign * self._score_func(y, y_pred, **self._kwargs)
    207 
    208     def _factory_args(self):

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py in roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score, average, sample_weight)
    275     return _average_binary_score(
    276         _binary_roc_auc_score, y_true, y_score, average,
--> 277         sample_weight=sample_weight)
    278 
    279 

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/base.py in _average_binary_score(binary_metric, y_true, y_score, average, sample_weight)
    116         y_score_c = y_score.take([c], axis=not_average_axis).ravel()
    117         score[c] = binary_metric(y_true_c, y_score_c,
--> 118                                  sample_weight=score_weight)
    119 
    120     # Average the results

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py in _binary_roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score, sample_weight)
    266     def _binary_roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score, sample_weight=None):
    267         if len(np.unique(y_true)) != 2:
--> 268             raise ValueError("Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score "
    269                              "is not defined in that case.")
    270 

ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case.
```

**My env:**

python==3.7.2

sklearn==0.19.2

**My question:**

Is it a bug, or I'm making a miss-use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An unnecessary annoyance with the cross-validation functionality of scikit-learn is that, by default, the data are not *shuffled*; it would arguably be a good idea to make shuffling the default choice - of course, this would pre-suppose that a shuffling argument would be available for `cross_val_score` in the first place, but unfortunately it is not ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)).

So, here is what is happening; the 150 samples of the iris dataset are *stratified*:

```
iris.target[0:50]
# result
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

iris.target[50:100]
# result:
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

iris.target[100:150]
# result:
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Now, a 3-fold CV procedure with 150 samples stratified as shown above and an error message saying:

```
ValueError: Only one class present in y_true
```

should hopefully start making sense: in each one of your 3 validation folds only one label is present, so no ROC calculation is possible (let alone the fact that in each validation fold the model sees labels unseen in the respective training folds).

So, just shuffle your data before:

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
X_s, y_s = shuffle(X, y)
cross_val_score(model, X_s, y_s, cv=3, scoring="roc_auc")
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: Whoo it works like a charm. I wrongfully thought cross val would do the suffling. Thanks