# Logistic regression failed to converge

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm learning classification algorithms and I'm trying to develop a binary classification model to predict if a picture is memorable or not memorable. I have a set of labeled data (extracted features from FC7) and I'm supposed to apply my classifier to unlabelled data. I chose logistic regression (is there a better option?), I'm just struggling with the final step, when I want to get the predictions for the unlabelled test data...

```
logisticRegr = LogisticRegression(solver = 'lbfgs')
logisticRegr.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
logisticRegr.predict(Xtest)
```

I get the error:

```
Convergence Warning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.
```

Any ideas what I can do? Increasing iterations doesnt help... :(

Comment: This is a warning and not an error, but it indeed may mean that your model is practically unusable. Be sure to [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302500/cross-val-score-is-not-working-with-roc-auc-and-multiclass/55309222#55309222) your data before fitting the model, and try different `solver` options. Scaling the input features might also be of help. If nothing works, it may indeed be the case that LR is not suitable for your data.

Comment: Well, notice that the warning comes actually from `fit`, **not** from `predict`!

Comment: Yes, I am provided with  provided with labelled training data, and another set of test data, which are not labelled. The task is to develop a binary-class classiﬁer (I guess, based on my labelled data) that predicts the labels for the test data... Thank you! Maybe I'll try different solvers indeed...